# How (and how often) does Git scan the working directory for "untracked" files?

Tags: git

Once you run git init on a directory, git knows about all files that exist in that directory and below. These are untracked files. I'm familiar enough (ish) with what happens when you stage those files and they become "tracked" files. But what I want to know is, how does Git find the untracked files? Does git run the tree command every few minutes or on fixed intervals? Does it run the tree command every time you type git status, or git add? Or every time you save a file? Is something cleverer going on?

So my questions in short:

1. How does Git find the untracked files?
2. How often does Git search for "untracked" files?

Comment: Git is an on demand tool. It performs its operations when you call it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the "how often" question. Does that mean it looks for untracked files whenever you run git add? Git status? Any git command?

Comment: "Does git run the tree command every few minutes or on fixed intervals?" No. Git doesn't do anything periodically or in the background.

Comment: It simply scans the working tree recursively any time _you_ give a command where Git would need to know whether you have any untracked files. You know perfectly well what commands those are: they are the commands where Git reports that you have untracked files.

Comment: "Git doesn't do anything periodically or in the background" it's not exactly related to the question but doesn't `gc` run periodically in the background? That's why I wasn't sure whether tracked/untracked files are enumerated periodically. Thanks for the clarification in any case!

Comment: There is no "list" of untracked files that Git is "maintaining"; your working tree _is_ the list, by trivial comparison with the index (and slightly less trivial comparison with the gitignore directives).

Comment: Okay, so the untracked files are the intersection/diff of all files that exists in the working directory, and all files that are tracked in the index? And in either case it basically does amount to a `tree`?

Comment: No. Even gc happens only if _you_ do something that triggers it (such as push).

Comment: There are no "tracked files in the index" unless you intend to be deliberately redundant. The files in the index are _exactly_ the tracked files. "Tracked" and "in the index" are synonyms.

Comment: Okay, so to rephrase: untracked files are the diff of the index and the worktree?

Comment: In effect and ignoring gitignore directives, yes. And Git is designed to obtain that diff REALLY FAST.

Comment: I say "in effect" because the index is not a file tree the way actual files on disk are.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the clarifications! You could put that in an answer and I'd accept it - theoretical bonus points if you know more about how git obtains that diff, but I've got the basic gist I think :)

Comment: Git is open source. If you really want to know how Git obtains the diff, go look. But basically the answer is that Git spins up a LOT of threads and takes FULL advantage of the capabilities of your platform's filesystem.

Comment: It's unlikely that git benefits a lot from multithreading when scanning changes. The hard disk is the bottleneck, not the cpu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *used to* have a simple and easy answer, 5 or more years ago.  Now, it's ... much more complicated.  However, the *behavior* today is supposed to match that of yore, so if you don't care about the actual implementation—and you're not supposed to *have to* care—we can describe the *old* implementation.

> Once you run git init on a directory, git knows about all files that exist in that directory and below.

That's not actually true: `git init` will create the `.git` directory / folder and populate it, but at this point Git hasn't looked in the working tree yet, other than to see if there's a `.git` there (so that `git init` in an existing repository "reinitializes" it, rather than creating a new repository—the reinitialization step usually does absolutely nothing, though technically it's defined as *copy template hooks* more or less).

It's true, however, that any existing files *in* the working tree are now untracked files:

> These are untracked files. I'm familiar enough (ish) with what happens when you stage those files and they become "tracked" files. But what I want to know is, how does Git find the untracked files?

Logically, Git does this simply by reading, laboriously, one entry at a time, through the top level of the working tree:

```
DIR *dirp = opendir(worktree);
```

in C code, followed by a loop calling `readdir`.

Each entry that comes back has several items.  If we assume the variable holding the `struct dirent *` pointer is named `dp`, we have at least two or three fields:

```
dp->d_name
dp->d_namlen
dp->d_type
```

The `d_type` field can contain `DT_UNKNOWN`, meaning that the system did not provide a file type, or `DT_REG` or `DT_DIR` or `DT_LNK` as three possibilities meaning "regular file", "directory" (folder), or "symbolic link".  (Other values are also possible on Unix-like systems, but Git won't store such entries.)

If the type is `DT_UNKNOWN`, Git will need to call `lstat` on the file's name, as constructed by combining the original `worktree` path with a slash and the C string in `dp->d_name` (it's NUL-terminated despite also having a `d_namlen` field).  That `lstat` call should succeed, and return all the usual information from any [stat system call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62).  Note that `lstat` calls are *very expensive* (much more so than opening and reading a directory, in general) so we want to avoid them whenever possible, and once done, we want to *keep that information as long as possible*.  So Git tends to do this; see more below.

Git can now look in `.gitignore` (or a data structure built by reading `.gitignore`) to see if a directory (`DT_DIR` or `S_ISDIR()`) should be skipped.  If so, this short-circuits all the recursion.  If not, for each directory, Git must do all of this same work recursively, but see below.

For things that *aren't* directories and *can* be stored in a repository, Git can now test to see whether this entry is already in Git's index—note that *directory* entries are not stored as index entries of this sort, but the index has "extensions" that *can* store them; we'll see more about this below—or not.  If a file found by this process *is* in Git's index, it is a *tracked file*.  If a file found by this process *is not* in Git's index, it's an *untracked file*.  That's pretty much all there is to tracked vs untracked.  Note that the tracked file, with information now stored in Git's index, has its `lstat` data transcribed as well, if we've done `lstat` on it.

> Does git run the tree command every few minutes or on fixed intervals?

(By "tree command", I'll assume you mean the logical read-tree-recursively operation I just described.)

Neither.  It scans the top level working tree on demand.

> Does it run the tree command every time you type git status, or git add?

For `git status`, yes.  For `git add`, only if you've used one of the "all" options, or asked `git add` to add an entity that is a directory, in which case it has to do the read-tree-recursively for the entity you named (provided it's not listed in a `.gitignore`).

> Is something cleverer going on?

Yes.  The description above is the *logic*, but the actual implementation tries to use shortcuts.  In addition, there is now a thing called the "fsmonitor daemon".

Probably the most important shortcut depends on some trickery that works well on Unix-like file systems, but maybe not on others.  This is the fact that *each directory has a modification time*.  This modification time shows up as the `st_ctime`<sup>1</sup> field of a `struct stat`, if you perform an `lstat` or `stat` system call on the directory.  We also know what *time* we last *wrote to Git's index*, as we store that in a field in the index.

Suppose we already know that `path/to/dir` *had*, say, eight untracked files in it, and know that they were all *ignored*.  Suppose further that we keep—somewhere—an entry for this `path/to/dir` entity that stores its `st_ctime` field.  And suppose we can `stat` it now and see that its ctime is *unchanged and predates the update to Git's index*.  Then we can be sure that it has not acquired any *new* untracked files, and therefore we could re-use the old information.

Git also uses this same kind of trick to avoid *rebuilding blob hash IDs* for all *tracked* files, where it's much more important.  This is easier than the *untracked cache*, so the *tracked* files (those listed in normal index entries) have had this kind of magic applied since early Git in 2005.

The untracked cache code went into Git 2.5, back in 2015, and it was kind of flaky for a long time, but it's pretty solid now.  Unfortunately it depends on assumptions that aren't true on NTFS (so it's often disabled on Windows systems).

Git gained something called the *fsmonitor* in 2017, as part of Git 2.16, and it too has been flaky.  There has been a lot of work on it recently to make it less flaky and to make it work on systems other than Windows: specifically, it now has macOS and Linux implementations.  The fsmonitor code is very different from the above: it listens for *file system operations reported by the OS*, which may occur in directories that aren't even in the working tree, and on some systems, some events might be *dropped* if the event queue fills up.

The job for the fsmonitor is basically to make it faster to update Git's index.  The details are still changing, so I won't attempt to describe it any further.

For technical information about what's in Git's index, see [the `Documentation/technical/index-format.txt` file in the Git repository for Git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt).

---

<sup>1</sup>You'd expect this to be `st_mtime`, and it would be, except that `st_mtime` can be set back on purpose via `utimes` or similar system calls.  However, there's a second field, `st_ctime`, that stores a generally non-decreasing value that *can't* be set back this way.  So we use `ctime`, the inode-change-time, instead of `mtime`, the modification time.  Backup software typically uses the same trick for incremental backups.

Comment: Fantastic, this is everything I was hoping for in an answer, thank you! And thanks for the detailed technical explanation, it's really helpful. So basically as @matt says, git only checks for untracked files when you run a command that would need to know whether you have any untracked files - it's not like it's doing this on a regular interval